# "There is no editor available for 'C:\Users\...\Form1.cs'." (Visual Studio 2013)

Tags: c#, visual-studio

My computer restarted when my solution was open, and now I get the following error whenever I try to open Form1.cs:

---

There is no editor available for 'C:\Users\Nick\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.cs'.

Make sure the application for the file type (.cs) is installed.

---

I can choose "Open With..." by right-clicking.
However, when I select "CSharp Form Editor (Default)", it opens a notepad file with roughly 5000 characters worth of spaces.

Comment: Wow, that is thorough! I will try this now, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Visual studio might have corrupted, repair it to bring it to normal

Comment: Yeah you're probably right, that makes me sad :[ Thank you though!!